# Elementary Question Regarding Classification of some Subsets of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: computability-theory

The question is regarding a few easily described subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. I have difficulty identifying which classification they fall into. These certainly feel like questions that would be present possibly as a routine exercise in an elementary textbook. But I haven't seen such questions (but perhaps this is more representative of lack of problem-solving experience).

Let $K$ denote the diagonal halt set. Similarly $H$ denote some set where we define two associated functions $c:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $\bar{c}:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. $c(x)$ is equal to the $x$-th smallest element when the elements of $H$ are enumerated in strictly increasing order. Similar definition holds for $\bar{c}$ for the complement.

As example if we have $H=\{1,5,6,8,....\}$ (strictly increasing order) then we have $c(0)=1$, $c(1)=5$, $c(2)=6$, $c(3)=8$. And similarly we have $\bar{c}(0)=0$, $\bar{c}(1)=2$, $\bar{c}(2)=3$, $\bar{c}(3)=4$, $\bar{c}(4)=7$.

Now proceeding to the actual question, we place some conditions on $H$. These are (i) H is r.e. (ii) $H \equiv_T K$ (iii) Both the functions $c$ and $\bar{c}$ are dominated by some total recursive function. Similarly we consider some function $\mathbb{b}:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and denote its image-set by $\mathbb{B}$. We place the following conditions on the function $\mathbb{b}:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ (i) $\mathbb{b}$ dominates every total recursive function (after finite number of values) (ii) $\mathbb{b}$ is strictly increasing (iii) $\mathbb{B} \equiv_T K$ (iv) $\mathbb{B}$ is co-r.e.

Now here are few questions (for obvious reasons, I have tried to choose few representative cases rather than be exhaustive). For the given set in each case, it has to be described that given the conditions on $H$ and $\mathbb{b}$, which of the following possibilities can or can't exist (i) given set is r.e. (ii) given set is co-r.e. (iii) neither.

**(Q0)** Define a function $f$ so that $f(x)=c(2x)$. Let $Z$ denote the image-set of the function $f$.

**(Q1)** First define a function $f$ so that we have $f(x)=c(c(x))$. Let $A$ denote the image-set of the function $f$.

**(Q2)** First define a function $f$ so that we have $f(x)=c(\bar{c}(x))$. Let $B$ denote the image-set of the function $f$.

**(Q3)** Define a function $f$ so that we have $f(x)=\mathbb{b}(c(x))$. Let $C$ denote the image-set of the function $f$.

**(Q4)** Define a function $f$ so that we have $f(x)=\mathbb{b}(\bar{c}(x))$. Let $D$ denote the image-set of the function $f$.

And here is one quite related question: **(Q5)** Does there exist a function $f$ (with image-set as $F$) such that (i)$f$ is strictly increasing (ii) $f$ dominates every total recursive function (after finite number of values) (iii) $F \equiv_T K$ (iv) $F$ is not co-r.e.

**P.S.** I posted the question on MSE (for reasons in the very first paragraph of question). Here is the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652150. But I didn't get a reference or a solution, nor I know a reference by myself (say as an example in a textbook). I have made some changes to MSE version of question (potentially to make it better and clearer).

**Edit:** Added (Q0) where the corresponding set is simpler to define than the other questions.

Comment: Here's an observation which you might find helpful (in particular, it gives an immediate positive answer to Q5). For $f, g$ functions, let $f* g$ be the function given by $(f*g)(n)=\langle f(n),g(n)\rangle$ where $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is some computable injective function satisfying $\langle a, b\rangle>a, b$ for all $a, b$. Then: (i) If either $f, g$ dominates every computable function, so does $f*g$. (ii) If $im(f*g)$ is r.e. (resp. co-r.e.), then so are both $im(f)$ and $im(g)$. (iii) We have $f*g\equiv_Tf\oplus g$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have a question regarding your comment. First of all, I guess you are assuming $f$ and $g$ to be total. Now (i) is correct. Regarding (ii), as I understand from wording, there are two separate statements (sorry if I misunderstood this). **(ii)a** If $im(f*g)$ is r.e. then both $im(f)$ and $im(g)$ are also r.e. **(ii)b** If $im(f*g)$ is co-r.e. then both $im(f)$ and $im(g)$ are also co-r.e. I can understand (ii)a to be correct. For (ii)b, are you assuming some further condition (apart from totality) on $f$ or $g$?

Comment: Whoops, yeah, the co-r.e. claim is nonsense; I was tired.